# How to run Rails on port 80 on AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, amazon-web-services, port

I'm trying to reboot Rails application on AWS Amazon Linux.
I rebooted the instance by AWS console, but I can't access to the service through port 80.

The conditions are:

1. Application was working fine before reboot.
2. Application works on port 3000.
3. Application can run on port 80 (like rails s -d -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80).
4. Security group of AWS says it's open 80 for HTTP on inbound.

Is there anything I have to check?

Comment: port must already have bind with web server like apache or nginx. which web server you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured out how:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

You can forward packets received on port 80 to port 3000 by this command. You can run the application on port 3000 then access on port 80.

But here a question is remained:

> Why rails s -d -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 (running application on port 80)
>   didn't work

[UPDATED]
This is because iptables didn't accept packets on port 80. You can configure it by the command of @hedgesky. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should save added rule; it could be cleared after restart otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You should ensure that OS itself has that port opened (AWS may block traffic for some ports on outer firewall level; it's not your case). Once I had similar issue, and these commands helped me:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

There was CentOS in my case, if it matters.